# How to Pass Back Slug to Render_Foo In Django?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

How do I pass a slug back through a *render_foo* with django-tables2?

```
models.py

class Library(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  library_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Author(models.Model):
  library = models.ForeignKey(Library)
  author_slug models.Slugfield(unqiue=True)

class Book(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
  book_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


views.py

def LibraryTableView(request):
  queryset = books.objects.values('author','book').annotate(book_count=Count('book'))
  table = LibraryTable(queryset)

def AuthorTableView(request, author_slug):
  queryset = books.objects.filter(book__author__author_slug=author_slug)
  table = AuthorTable(queryset)


tables.py

class LibraryTable(tables.Table):
  class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ('author', 'book_count')

  def render_book_count(self, value, author_slug):
    return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', author_slug, value)
```

Library Table
| Author| Book Count |
|--------|------------|
| JK Rowling | 6 |
| Brandon Sanderson| 12 |
| Herman Melville | 5 |

When clicking on author Herman Melville, it will drill down to his books

| Title | Genre |
| --- | --- |
| Typee | Non-Fict |
| Omoo | Fict |
| Redburn | Fict |
| Moby-Dick | Fict |
| Timoleon | Poetry |

Note: If I try `author = tables.Column(linkify=True)`, I get the error `for linkify=True, Herman Mellville must have a method get_absolute_url`

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of things, the easiest way would be to use linkify and add a get_absolute_url method.

```
class Author(models.Model):
  library = models.ForeignKey(Library)
  author_slug models.Slugfield(unqiue=True)
  def get_absolute_url(self):
      """Returns a permalink for the author"""
      return reverse(
          "AuthorTableView",
          kwargs={"author_slug": self.slug},
      )
```

The advantage of setting it up this way is that if you change your URL structure, this will update automatically.  Hardcoding your HTML format href would break if if you made such a change.

If you do want to hardcode it, despite this, then you'll need to make sure your hardcoded URL ends up like what your url file expects for your AuthorTableView.  Eg, if your url file has
`'/author/<str:slug>'` then you'll want

```
  def render_book_count(self, value, record):
      return format_html('<a href="/author/{}">{}</a>', record.slug, value)
```

The important difference here is that 'value' is the column value for the book_count column, and record is the entire row, that you can interrogate for other parts of the model with 'record.*property*'.

Update after comment:

In addition, you don't need to use 'values' in your LibraryTableView.  Try:

```
 queryset = Author.objects.annotate(book_count=Count('book'))
```

This will keep your author as an object with a get_absolute_url() method.  You will need to update your LibraryTable class Meta: appropriately as it's really an author model you're using.

Comment: I set up the model as described and set ```linkify=True``` but I still get the error ```for linkify=True, 'Herman Melville' must have a method get_absolute_url```.  I believe this is because I am calling ```author.object.values()``` rather than ```author.objects.all().```.  If I use the latter, it works, but I lose the aggregation.

Comment: True - I had neglected that. I have updated the answer to account for it.